# How do I parse json using the objects name?

Tags: json

I have a json that looks like this:

```
{
  "action": x,
  "application": x,
  "params": {},
  "path": x,
  "uri": x,
  "entities": [
    {
      ... user data such as:
      "name":"john smith"
    }
  ],
  "timestamp": x,
  "duration": x,
  "organization": x,
  "applicationName": x,
  "count": x
}
```

I've used x's to hide data.

I'm trying to use data.entities["name"] to get the person's name. I'm not getting anything back though and can't tell what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

```
data.entities[0]["name"]
```

because data.entities is an array of objects

Answer (score 0):

`data.entities` is an array of objects.  In order to get at the data in question you have to index it at `0`

```
data.entities[0]["name"]
```

Comment: I tried that but the system returns "Cannot read property '0' of undefined" I know it's "entities" and I've tested the data returned and it's valid

Comment: Then the data format you put above is incorrect.  See here, this is a direct copy and paste (I added x = "" to make it work): http://jsfiddle.net/h6yz11gn/

Please make sure that the data is exactly the same